# Handling connection error stomp 0.3.3 flutter/dart

Tags: spring, flutter, dart

When I put a wrong url/ip to my stomp spring service I don't get onWebSocketError fired up and does not print out error as in the code below:

```
final stompClient = StompClient(
  config: StompConfig(
    url: 'ws://localhostxx:8080',
    onConnect: onConnect,
    onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
    stompConnectHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer yourToken'},
    webSocketConnectHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer yourToken'}));
```

I want to show a message to a user that the connection is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 0.4.0 the `onWebSocketError` callback should be more reliably called when errors occur.

https://pub.dev/packages/stomp_dart_client/changelog#040